# C++ enum of types

Tags: c++

I wish to use a collection of types in a variant template `std::variant<type0, type1, type2, ..., typen>`. `typen` can be anything such as an `int` or `std::vector<int>` say. Is there a way to abbreviate `type0, type1, type2, ..., typen` in a type enum of some sort?? I'm trying not to write `std::variant<type0, type1, type2, ..., typen>` every time.

Comment: Just make a type alias for your `std::variant<...>`

Comment: `using my_variant = std::variant<int, vector<int>>;`

Comment: I could benefit from accessing individual ```typen``` later on. So I'd prefer not to alias the variant.

Comment: Since you don't want to use the C++ way to abbreviate it, then you could resort to macros.  I don't recommend macros, since they are pure concentrated evil™.

Comment: But alias does nothing to `typen`. It just gives you another name you can use instead of `std::variant<type0, type1, type2, ..., typen>`. It changes nothing else. You can still do `using my_variant = std::variant<int, vector<int>>; std::get<int>(my_variant_instance);`

Comment: That wasn't the question. Macros aren't necessarily the solution either.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: So you want something shorter to type than `variant<type0, type1, ...>`, but you also still want to refer to `type0` later. Do the two need to be related in some way? Do you want shorter names for `type0`, `type1` etc. as well? What are some examples of how you want to use these type names?

Comment: often a collection of types can be represented by a `std::tuple` of that types, though as you want to use a `std::variant` anyhow, the tuple won't have any benefit over aliasing the variant directly. Can you give an example of what you are looking for?

Comment: maybe part of the misunderstanding is that you say "in a type enum of some sort" and you seem to mean something by that, but it is unclear what that should be

Comment: What is your goal with this question? Is it to get an answer?

Answer (score 3):

You want a type alias: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias

```
using short_name = std::variant<type0,type1,type2, ..., typen>;
```

> I could benefit from accessing individual typen later on. So I'd prefer not to alias the variant

Thats no reason to not use a type alias. You can still use `type0` etc. And to get the n-th type of the variant there is `std::variant_alternative_t`:

```
 static_assert( std::is_same_v< type0, std::variant_alternative_t<0,short_name> > );
```